# Weight loss between harvest and pre roasting

Tags: whole-bean

My questionn being as to how much weight loss is there between coffee beans been harvested and when it is dry enough to roast.If no answer, someone might how much volume loss there is.
Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Dry enough = 12% moisture content
Weight loss by roasting = 12-18% of green bean weight
Volume loss = opposite; coffee beans puff up after roasting